# SharePoint : how to authenticate from c#

Tags: sharepoint

I have the following code snippet:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(this.ListAddress))
        {
            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
            {

            }

        }
```

How can I authenticate so that I can set a domain username + password in a configuration file.

Comment: For future visitors, could you clarify which version of SharePoint this is for? I stumbled upon this and couldn't tell if it was 2007, 2010, or something else.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make the user you want to run the code under known in SharePoint, then, using

`SPSite.RootWeb.EnsureUser("username").UserToken` you can get that user's SPUserToken
use that to open the SPSite, like so

```
var token = SPSite.RootWeb.EnsureUser("usernameToImpersonate").UserToken;

using (SPSite site = new SPSite(token, this.ListAddress))
{
  using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
  {
    // code here will be executed as selected user
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The code run above will autheticate under the current users identity, i.e. the identity of the user running the current thread.

You can run code under a different user using the NetworkCredntial class together with the WindowsIdentity class

See these two aticles:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkcredential%28VS.71%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.aspx

Comment: This isn't the recommended approach for SharePoint. Much simpler to use Colin's code sample.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly clear what you want to do from the question. However if you are looking for impersonation, note that you can pass through an [SPUserToken](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spusertoken.aspx) object in the [SPSite constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsite.spsite.aspx).

Any objects you then create from the impersonated SPSite object will behave as if they have been created by that user.